# ChannelOutputShutdownException on spark streaming queries

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have been running `spark structured streaming` for some time but am now seeing the following exception:

```
ChannelOutputShutdownException: Channel output shutdown
```

This is happening after

```
val flights2a = (spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  .option("subscribe", "airjpart3")
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
  .option("max.poll.records", "20000")
  .load())
```

and then several queries to restructure the data.  Here is the more of the stacktrace:

```
[0719-22:47:31.061] INFO: select * from airsyFilt
19/07/19 22:48:04 ERROR TransportClient: Failed to send RPC RPC 7871969257559858384 to mellyrn/192.168.0.3:51492: io.netty.channel.socket.ChannelOutputShutdownException: Channel output shutdown
io.netty.channel.socket.ChannelOutputShutdownException: Channel output shutdown
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.shutdownOutput(AbstractChannel.java:587)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:893)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0(AbstractNioChannel.java:313)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush(AbstractChannel.java:847)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:762)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:743)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.flush(ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter.java:115)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:762)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.flush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:743)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelDuplexHandler.flush(ChannelDuplexHandler.java:117)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:770)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:762)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1500(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:35)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$WriteAndFlushTask.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1116)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$AbstractWriteTask.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1050)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:399)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:464)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.network.util.AbstractFileRegion.transferred()J
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.AbstractFileRegion.transfered(AbstractFileRegion.java:28)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel.doWrite(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:232)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWrite(NioSocketChannel.java:282)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0(AbstractChannel.java:879)
    ... 21 more
19/07/19 22:48:04 ERROR OneForOneBlockFetcher: Failed while starting block fetches
java.io.IOException: Failed to send RPC RPC 7871969257559858384 to mellyrn/192.168.0.3:51492: io.netty.channel.socket.ChannelOutputShutdownException: Channel output shutdown
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient$RpcChannelListener.handleFailure(TransportClient.java:357)
```

Has anyone seen this / have insight?

**Update1**  At first this problem seemed to be due to putting excessive pressure on memory resources on the Workers.  The `WriteStream` is as follows:

```
def writes(sdf: Dataset[_], table: String, interval: String = "20 seconds", outputMode: String = "complete") = {
val outDf = (sdf.writeStream
  .outputMode(outputMode)
  .format("memory")
  .queryName(table)
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(interval))
  .start())
```

The table being written had too much data to adequately be stored.  The error message did not really make that clear as being the issue.

Based on another answer I am providing the evidence of the *data size* being the culprit. The update to a sql that avoids the issue is adding a `limit N` as follows:

```
select * from airsyFilt limit 100000
```

I was running the original sql for diagnostics purposes: the production app only needs aggregates and thus I can afford to make this change.

**Update2**   Even with small to moderate data sizes the above error is occurring.  I had not seen in my five+ years of spark .  There is a mention of this recently in the spark mailing list so I am presently  trying out a downgrade to spark 2.3.3 (from 2.4.2). Will update here..

Downgrade to spark 2.3.3 had no effect.  So this is an outstanding issue still..

**Update3** This code **works fine** on another machine .  The only customisations to *Spark* itself is setting the `log4j.properties` to being much more stingy/parsimonious. And I did that same change on *both* machines.

One machine (that is not working just past 24 hours) is Macos Mojave. The other is Centos.  Usually Spark does well cross platform but not sure here..

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have found that NoSuchMethodError occurs whenever you have incompatible jars in your dependency list.
I strongly feel that the some of the jars that you are using to run your application are not compatible with each other. Kindly have a look at the versions.

Comment: While  `NoSuchMethodError` commonly occurs when you say - instead in _this_ case by simply adding a `limit N` to the `sql` fixed it. So clearly it is not a libraries versioning problem.   I am updating my answer with that `limit 100000` sql that avoids the problem.